# T-SQL Order by whitespace ordering

Tags: t-sql, sql-order-by, whitespace

I would like to ask you about this simple ORDER BY (in T-SQL) clause.
Let's say we have these varchars in a table. (the table has ID, name, other columns)

```
'Peter'
''
''
'Anna'
'Michael'
'Bert'
''
''
''
```

The goal is to order them in ascending order, but so that the whitespaces will follow and not proceed these names. (I know that it sounds a little bit illogical, but I need all the datarows - including whitespaces - the table has in reality more columns and I cannot change  anything). Of course, the code of these chars precede the alphabet, but how to trick it to produce this output?

`SELECT name FROM table ORDER BY name`

```
'Anna'
'Bert'
'Michael'
'Peter'
''
''
''
''
''
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) in `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT 
   name 
FROM 
   dbo.table 
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN name IS NULL OR name='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC
 , name ASC
```

This query will first split all into two groups:

1. with name
2. without name

Then it will order by the first group first, then by the name itself. Then it'll append the group without name.

Comment: in which SQL version ? 2005+ ?

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me: [**CASE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258235(v=sql.80).aspx) was already there in 2000.  However, if you use sql-server 2000 you should tag that explixitely because many things have changed since then.